# Lazy Load won't load visible images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lazy-loading

I'm trying to use lazyload to only load images that are visible (because my site is responsive and some content is hidden with display:none to clients on a smaller screen).

Basically, lazyload works, but ONLY after I scroll the page a little.

This is the lazy load settings I'm using, and even after setting the threshold to 2000px (more than the entire page height) it still only loads images after the user scrolls the page (even 1 px).
This bug only appears in webkit browsers.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").lazyload({threshold : "2000", effect : "fadeIn", effectspeed: 2000,});
});
```

Comment: I've had this problem as well.

Comment: Don't know if it's the problem or not, but `threshold` is supposed to be a integer, i.e. `threshold: 2000`, not `threshold: "2000"`.

Comment: Yeah, it makes no difference, Chris - still the same problem.

Comment: What happens if you trigger the `scroll` event of the page using jquery. Not necessary to move the page scroll - just to trigger it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it could be some misbehavior of `threshold` parameter, but still you can manually fire the loading according to [this page](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("img")
         .lazyload({
             event: "lazyload",
             effect: "fadeIn",
             effectspeed: 2000
           })
         .trigger("lazyload");
  });
</script>
```

but if you want to load all images on `ready`, why need lazyload at all? You could just use `$.animate`.

Comment: This seems to load all images no matter where they are on the page now, even out of viewport ones.
I don't want to load all images on ready, I want to load them ONLY if they're on screen, as I stated.
That's because I got a lot of hidden content that's only served to mobile devices and don't want them downloading massive images they can't view anyway.

Comment: You life saver! Thanks, I wasn't aware of this event method.

Comment: If you only want images to be shown for your mobile users, add the class "mobile" to this images.
Then use the above event only for $("img.mobile").

Answer (score 5):

Just add this after .lazyload() and it will trigger scroll and show images

```
$(window).trigger('scroll');
```

Comment: Then why use lazy load at all?

Comment: It will not show all images, just those that are visible.

Comment: Well, it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set width and height for you images.

If width and height are not set jQuery will report images invisible in Webkit browsers on document.load event. When `skip_invisible` is `true` Lazy Load will ignore the images, meaning  it wont try to figure out whether image should be loaded or not. They will load first time you scroll.

If you set `skip_invisible` is `false` plugin will try to figure out should images be loaded. However since you do not have width and height set all images will be size of 0x0 or 1x1. Because of this all images are in viewport (because of their size) when plugin kicks in. Because images are in viewport Lazy Load will instruct to load them all.

In short: Add width and height to images. Lazy Load wont work properly without them.

Comment: You are correct to a certain degree, but there must be a bug somewhere with this, because it doesn't always work. Firing the event manually after initialization fixes this - as user pozs above suggests.

Comment: URL of the page you are referring to?

Comment: The commenter above - pozs

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure when this got added, but you can manually fire the 'appear' event to some or all (depending on the css selector) appear:

```
$("img.lazy").trigger('appear');
```

Got this from here: http://yuji.wordpress.com/2014/05/14/force-jquery-lazyload-to-appear/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  They are in a scrolling div, but would only load after an initial scroll.

Using 'appear' will show them all, unless you limit it.  In my case, I only wanted to show the first 3 on load.  The rest of them lazy load as usual.

```
$("img.lazy:lt(3)").trigger('appear');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass additional parameter.

skip_invisible : false

This parameter is true by default, so it seems your images are not visible when plugin starts it's job. It could happens when you are using any preloader on your website.

Comment: Well yeah, but that sort of defeats the purpose of lazy loading images if they just load even if they're hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found a solution for this.
Please note that my images were placed inside of a div that is populated via an ajax call.

Just change a line of code inside the lazyload sources (lines 147-150) of version 1.8.4:

```
/* Force initial check if images should appear. */
        $(document).ready(function() {
            update();
        });
```

instead of

```
/* Force initial check if images should appear. */
        $(window).load(function() {
            update();
 });
```

Or eventually add the call to "update()" to any other needed event.

Comment: This has been fixed in 1.8.5.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the images wouldn't load after a ajax call until I scrolled (even if I just scrolled 1px it would load). I found I needed to add a height and width to my images like Mika Tuupola said. My images were loaded dynamically, were different image sizes and loaded from a foreach loop. I added generic width and height attribute to the image tag then after the lazyload loads the image I removed the attributes so it would show the correct image size.

```
<img class="lazy" src="img/placeholder.gif" data-original="img/image.gif" width="1000" height="600">

$('img.lazy').lazyload({
    skip_invisible: false
}).removeClass('lazy').removeAttr('width').removeAttr('height');
```

Comment: Nice hack, but you can fire the event manually like pozs says above, seems to work for all situations you'd need it.

Comment: Pozs solution above unconditionally just loads all images as soon as document.ready event is fired. Effect is basically the same as not using Lazy Load plugin at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with hidden elements, is a simple workaround but it works. When I click on the page, I triggering scroll event to force lazyload script. You can do the same thing with the event resize

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").lazyload({
        event: "lazyload",
        effect: "fadeIn",
        effectspeed: 2000
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $(this).trigger("scroll");
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In short: Add width and height to images. Lazy Load wont work properly without them.

You should be loaded in advance placeholder;Like this：

```
<img src="./images/grey.gif" alt="" style="display:none">
```

And then

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({placeholder : "images/grey.gif"});
```

If you set the width of the image to 100%,this will provide a width and height.
This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is working solution, but in is not very good for some reason:

```
$("img").lazyload({
    /* Image loaded callback function */
    load: function() {
        $(window).trigger('scroll');
    }
});
```

Every time lazyload plugin load the picture, this function will be called and window trigger 'scroll' will be emulated, so it is a solution for me

Answer (score 0):

Increase the **failure_limit**.

After scrolling page plugin loops though unloaded images. Loop checks if image has become visible. By default loop is stopped when first image outside viewport is found. This is based on following assumption. Order of images on page is same as order of images in HTML code. With some layouts assumption this might be wrong.

Setting failure_limit to 10 causes plugin to stop searching for images to load after finding 10 images below the fold.

Answer (score -1):

I was dealing with the same issue and I noticed that this problem only occurs when images are placed inside a div that is initially hidden (ie. display: none;)